# How to disable cache in nginx when upload file

Tags: caching, upload, nginx

We configure nginx as front server, and jetty as the backend server. When we upload file, nginx will cache the uploading file, and then send to the jetty server. 
Can anyone tell me how to disable the cache function in nginx? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed we don't have to disable nginx cache. We can use [this link](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule). to handle file upload progress.